# Removing white space from below the footer pushed out by hidden elements

Tags: html, css

I have a three column design where the right most column contains a large number of 'Divs' that encapsulate collapsed info that can be scrolled through with the centre mouse wheel overflow being hidden. The the three columns are set to 760px with a footer below that. It all sits nicely and looks good BUT the page continues down to about 4000px (my guess is the size of the hidden elements).

What I have tried:
body, page wrap, column, in column wrapper all set max-height, made no difference.
added a red border to all page elements (idea from a stack overflow post) nothing visible down there to push it out.
some tentative testing with vh vw numbers but no luck.

Here is a snippet of the top of the column but the are 36 more divs below this:

```
<aside id="option_sidebar" class="content_rounds">
    <h2>Scientists:</h2>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="option op1">
            <img src="../images/Science/Michael_Archer.jpg" alt=""><h3>Michael Archer</h3>
            <div class="collapse_wrap">
            <p>Australian Scientists - Fossils</p>
            <a href="http://www.smh.com.au/national/waking-the-dead-20130617-2ocz4.html" target="_blank">Resource link 1</a>
            <a href="http://www.ted.com/speakers/michael_archer.html" target="_blank">Resource link 2</a>
            <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErexJkoDhGI" target="_blank">Resource link 3</a>
            <a href="http://science.org.au/fellows/feature-fellow/archer/index.html" target="_blank">Resource link 4</a>
            <a href="http://www.keynotes.org/speaker/michaelarcher" target="_blank">Resource link 5</a>
            <a href="http://oconnoroz.wordpress.com/tag/mike-archer-paleontologist/" target="_blank">Resource link 6</a>
            <a href="http://lifeboat.com/ex/bios.michael.archer" target="_blank">Resource link 7</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

These are the styles that are being directly applied to the column:

```
#option_sidebar {
    width: 260px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    float: left;
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:760px;
    }

.content_rounds{
    border-radius: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #8b8b7a;
    border: solid 1px #8b8b7a;
    }/*don't think this matters*/

#option_sidebar .inner{
    overflow: auto;
    max-height:700px;
    margin:0px -50px 20px 0px;
    padding-right:35px;
    }

.option{
    border: solid 1px #8b8b7a;
    width:94%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin:5px 10px 5px 0px;
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

.option img{
    display: inline;
    max-width:70px;
    max-height:100px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    margin:5px;
    }

.option h3, .option h4, .option h5{
    display:inline;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    position:relative;
}

.option a{
    display:block;
}


.op1:hover  > .collapse_wrap  {
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
    visibility: visible;
    position:relative;
    opacity: 1 ;
    }

.op1 h3{
    padding-top:10px;

    }
```

I hope that there is enough detail to assist but not so much as to bore,

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: I've put together the example you've given but I can't see the issue you've described. Could you try to create an example which reproduces the problem? Here are some tips on creating a [mcve].

Comment: Based on the info given, my guess would be to look at whether you're using `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` in your CSS rules. The former still occupies space (it's just invisible), the latter removes it from the layout.

Comment: @cmrm I'm not sure how I would use 'visibility:hidden' or 'display:none' as the divs that are within the column area need to be visible, I have used 'overflow: hidden' . Did you need more of the structure of the site? if you are trying to cause the fault I can provide more code if needed but you might just be able to duplicate the provided div thirty odd times.

Comment: Any chance of posting the page URL?

Comment: If you could provide a full example that would be a big help. You can use a site like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to upload an example if it's too large to include in your question. It would be good to have the context of the problem (in this case, the other columns and the footer) as I can't see the problem you've described by just duplicating the divs given in the current example. If we can't reproduce the problem we can't help you solve it!

Comment: @Cynthia sorry it isn't live yet just living on my thumb drive will see if I can host it not though

Comment: Also just as an aside this site will probably never be completely live but will reside in the schools intranet for use by our teacher librarian.

Comment: I think I have now hosted it on my Google drive? please let me know if it doesn't work optimisation tips will also be appreciated.[my site](https://abe84a21a92b6abfaea0936e4798b87353268064.googledrive.com/host/0B-Fy6Jqmy0PqbUdZd2V1QVlPV2M/library_web/index.html) the offending page is year 7 science.

Comment: @cmrn  thank you so much for you patient assistance. Can you get the code you need from the hosted site?

Comment: @Cynthia I forgot to add you in the site posting message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing a full example in your comments!

You can resolve your problem by adding `position: relative;` to either the `.op1` div, the `.inner` div, or the `#option_sidebar`.

From the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):
[The `relative`] keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned).
More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thanks @cmrn I knew it would be an easy fix, but spent so long at it!!  Now I feel like a bit of a dill! :-P  Any optimisation tips would be appreciated too.

Comment: No worries! One thing I'd suggest you look at is making sure that there's a scroll bar on the scrolling column so that people know they can scroll. To do this, remove the `overflow: hidden` from `#option_sidebar`, make sure the `overflow` setting on `inner` is set toto `auto` or `scroll`, then adjust the margin to position it properly.

Comment: The scroll bar was hidden on purpose I think it makes for a cleaner look. The site will be used as a teaching tool so any confusion about the scroll can be taught to, the three students I let test it went straight to the scroll with out prompting. So I'm pretty confident it'll be alright but will keep it in mind if we have any access issues.